# Elevation for FAB doesn't work

Tags: android, widget, floating-action-button, android-elevation

I'm trying to test FAB from android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

When I set elevation from the xml layout, the shadow shows the elevation.

When I try to change elevation programmatically:

```
fab.setElevation(9);
```

I get an error saying that my API should be raised from 14 to 21.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Elevation is only available on API 21+

Comment: Chol, but why elevation works for API 14 through xml? That was the question.

Comment: Actually througt the xml it will be ignored if API<21 and there will be no shadow. In Eclipse, on the xml you can see a warning : Attribute "elevation" is only used in API level 21 and higher (current min is 11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is used for an ImageButon, not a FAbButton, but it simulates the Fab:
what you can do it is create a fab-btn.xml in drawable folder to simulate the shadow:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
    <layer-list>
        <item android:bottom="0dp" android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#44000000" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="@color/orange" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:shape="oval" android:top="2dp">
        <solid android:color="#E73700" />
    </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

In your main layout on the fab button:

```
 android:background="@drawable/fab_btn"
 android:elevation="5dp"
```

If it is API 21+ it will take the levation, if not it will take the fab_btn.xml. It is up to you to update this file to have the desired shadow

Comment: But you could you please explain why elevation works for API 14 through xml?

Answer (score 2):

For fab elevation use :

```
    fab.setCompatElevation(8f); //API>=21
```

This method :

```
    fab.setElevation(8f); // Works only for API >=21 for other layouts
```

Elevation only works for API>=21